# Running MSVC compiler from Java code gives error

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compilation

I am trying to compile some C++ source file with *MSVC2008* compiler from Java code. E.g. i have a path to the source file and the path to ms compiler. I need to run compiler and get the executable file path or an error status. But everything i get so far is *"No include paths defined"* error and the exit status of `2`.

Googling a bit gave me the `vsvars32.bat` file path which fixed this error when running from a raw `cmd`. But it seems that Java has its own environment, totally different from the OS one when running a process with `ProcessBuilder`.

So far i've got this code:

```
compilerPath = String.format("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe\" \"%s\"", sourcePath);

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(compilerPath);
Process process = builder.start();
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
process.waitFor();
```

This returns `exitValue == 2` and the error mentioned above any time i run it.

How this can be fixed so i can just run `cl.exe` and get my executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to set `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variables for the `ProcessBuilder` and its `Process`'es:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cl.exe main.cpp /nologo".split("\\s+"));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.environment().put("INCLUDE", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\include;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Include");
builder.environment().put("LIB", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Lib");

Process process = builder.start();

process.waitFor();
```

Comment: @Jordfräs sure it does not! At least, paths are totally incorrect for VS 10. Don't know about the compiler command itself, but I believe it stays same.

Comment: I mean even when changing the paths. I think you have to run the vcvarsall.bat script (or check in detail what it sets up, which I didn't have time for).

Comment: @Jordfräs originally the question was about `MSVC2008`, so... But I know the differences are - I just have no chance to check it in the nearest future.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run `cl.exe` if it is just in your PATH. It is not a java question. It is the configuration of your OS.

The problem is that probably you cannot configure environment of every machine where you are running your application. And other possible problem is that probably the compiler must be executed in specific directory (e.g. in the project directory).

Obviously the spaces in path add yet another level of complexity.

First try to do exactly the same from command prompt. There is a chance that it will fail too and will print the reason.

If it works return to your java code but try to read the STOUT and STDERR of `cl.exe`. I believe it prints something that can help you to understand what's the problem.

Comment: nope, adding cl.exe and/or its parent dir did nothing. i am still getting this content in stdout and stderr: `Output: 27870395166881.cpp27870395166881.cpp(1) : fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set
Errors: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`